# A series expansion of a function at a non-differentiable point

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

*[Repost from MSE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4374009/a-series-expansion-of-a-function-at-a-non-differentiable-point)*

The function $x\mapsto (\frac{x}{1+x})^{x+x^2}$ is not differentiable in $0$, but nevertheless I'm interested in a series expansion at $0$. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series%20of%20%28x%2F%281%2Bx%29%29%5E%28x%2Bx%5E2%29%20in%200) tells me it has the *Puiseux series* expansion

$$1 + x \log x + \mathcal O(x^2).$$

How do you compute this series expansion (or any "non-Taylor" Puiseux series expansion) over the reals?

---

It may be that the series expansion is easy to compute by making an educated guess first. If that is the case I'd prefer an answer without this "hindsight".

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) on Puiseux series has a strong algebraic focus related to polynomials, so I can't easily tell whether that information is really all the relevant to the case of real functions.

The [Mathworld article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PuiseuxSeries.html) on this topic is also very short. I wonder what the reason is that according to their definition (iterated) logarithms (as in the above example) can also appear, alongside fractional powers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^{x+x^2}.$$
Expand first
$$g(x)=\log f(x)=(x+x^2)(\log x-\log(1+x))=x\log x+x^2\log x-x^2-\frac{1}{2}x^3-\ldots.$$
This has only two terms with $\log$, the rest are powers.
So powers of $g$ have the same property: they contain powers of $\log$ and ordinary powers. And then use
$$f=e^g=1+g+\frac{g^2}{2}+\frac{g^3}{6}+\ldots,$$
and substitute the series of $g$ to this series.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the example. Does a similar method work in the general case or is there a reference where I can find a theorem about this? I still don't get the jump from the definition with fractional powers to having logs.

Comment: @Stefan Perko: What do you mean by the "general case"? Not every function has an asymptotic expansion in terms of powers and logs. Asymptotic expansions can be written in terms of various "scales" (systems of functions). See, for example Bourbaki, Functions of a real variable.

Comment: Of course with "general case" I was referring to a reasonably large class of functions for which such an asymptotic expansion is known to exist, similar to functions being $C^k$ at $0$ for the Maclaurin case.  Thanks for the reference, I will check it out.

Comment: Expansions in terms of powers, exponentials and logarithms frequently occur in the theory of differential equations, where they are known under the name "transseries". Search on this word in Wikipedia. I cannot say more, until you ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will look into the term. - the topic is just so foreign to me I didn't even know where to start.